# context.Request.Files[0] is empty in FireFox,

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, httpcontext

I want to file Upload

The code is like this :

```
int iTotal = context.Request.Files.Count;   
if(iTotal>0)
  //Upload()....
```

It works fine when I use IE7,8,9
But when I use it in FireFox 8 , it doesn't work anymore.
iTotal always equal 0.

Are there any ideas/suggestions to me?
EDIT:

I have two page. In page A

```
 $("idBtnupload").onclick = function()
   { 
     ... 
    fu.Form.submit(); 
    } 
<form id="uploadForm" action="File.ashx?type=<% =type %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="button" value="开始上传" id="idBtnupload" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: No more guesses! You have to show more code so anyone can suggest.

Comment: I have two page. Page A is `$("idBtnupload").onclick = function(){ ...   fu.Form.submit();
} <form id="uploadForm" action="File.ashx?type=<% =type %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="button" value="开始上传" id="idBtnupload" /> </form> />`

Comment: Page B is  ashx . main method is  ` public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    { int iTotal = context.Request.Files.Count;  }`  here ,iTotal always equal 0 when i use FireFox8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `"runat='server'"` attribute to your input file

example:

```
 <input type="file" id="myfile1" runat="server" >
```

Comment: I tried it . but it didn't work . In this article [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetHandlerAjaxUpload.aspx).the author said what the key point is it is use Context.Request.InputStream in FireFox , but when i tried it ,i still couldn't get the filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ffFileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];

if ((null == ffFileName) && (0 == context.Request.Files.Count))
  return;

string tempDir = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FilesTempDir"];
string filePath = String.Format("{0}{1}", tempDir, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

if (null != ffFileName)
{
  Stream inputStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
  byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(inputStream);

  File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);
}
else
{
  HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[0];
  file.SaveAs(filePath);

}

context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.Write("{\"success\": true}");
```

This is method for read stream

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  int read;
  while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

}